# Can we allocate output of a select query to variable in a while loop in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to see if a output of select query can be allocated to a variable in while loop in postgresql

```
do $$
declare 
   turn_var integer := 1;
   sum_weight   := 0;
begin
   while turn_var < 7 loop
      sum_weight := select sum(weight) from line where turn <= turn_var
      if sum_weight <= 1000 then
      RETURN QUERY select name from line where turn = turn_var ;
      exit ;
      end if;
      turn_var := turn_var + 1;
   end loop;
end$$;
```

Comment: More often than not, a loop is the wrong approach in SQL. It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve.  Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: You didn't ask a question... Maybe you want to try to put the query in the `sum_weight := ...` assignment in `()` and terminate the assignment with `;`?